# Dependency error (yeoman-generator) while trying to install webpack-cli

Tags: npm, webpack, dependencies, installation

I've followed the instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-cli/tutorial but am getting this error:

```
$ npm install webpack-cli
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for yeoman-generator@ev1stensberg-generator-Feature-getArgument.tar.gz-art-external
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'webpack-cli'
npm ERR! notarget
```

I searched for `yeoman-generator` and installed it, but still get the same error. How can I get around this?

Comment: Turns out I didn't have the latest packages because I was pointing to my company's internal registry. Using `npm config` to change the registry back to default solved the issue. Closing.

Comment: Some NPM setups, such as when behind a proxy, have issues resolving git dependencies. Hopefully this will be resolved soon in https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/161

Comment: My moronic company block github.com so was having issues too